# Force consistent conversion of null to nan when using toPandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pyspark

The `toPandas` method in pyspark is not consistent for null values in numerical columns. Is there a way to force it to be more consistent?

**An example**

`sc` is the sparkContext. The spark version is 2.3.2. I'm not sure how to include notebook results, but I'll just comment the outputs. It's pretty straightforward, and you can check it yourself in a notebook.

```
sparkTest = sc.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1,    1   ),
        (2,    None),
        (None, None),
    ],
    ['a', 'b']
)
sparkTest.show() # all None values are neatly converted to null

pdTest1 = sparkTest.toPandas()
pdTest1 # all None values are NaN
np.isnan(pdTest1['b']) # this a series of dtype bool

pdTest2 = sparkTest.filter(col('b').isNull()).toPandas()
pdTest2 # the null value in column a is still NaN, but the two null in column b are now None
np.isnan(pdTest2['b']) # this throws an error
```

This is of course problematic when programming, and not being able to predict beforehand if a column will be all nulls.

Incidentally I wanted to report this as an issue, but I'm not sure where. The [github page](https://github.com/apache/spark) doesn't seem to have an issues section?

Answer (score 1):

`np.isnan` can be applied to NumPy arrays of native dtype (such as np.float64), but raises `TypeError` when applied to object arrays:

```
pdTest1['b']
0    1.0
1    NaN
2    NaN
Name: b, dtype: float64

pdTest2['b']
0    None
1    None
Name: b, dtype: object
```

If you have pandas, you could use `pandas.isnull` instead:

```
import pandas as pd


pd.isnull(pdTest1['b'])
0    False
1     True
2     True
Name: b, dtype: bool


pd.isnull(pdTest2['b'])
0    True
1    True
Name: b, dtype: bool
```

Which is consistent for both `np.nan` and `None`.

Alternatively, you could (if possible given your data), cast your `pdTest2['b']` array as one of the native `numpy` types (such as `np.float64`) to ensure `np.isnan` is working, such as:

```
pdTest2 = sparkTest.filter(f.col('b').isNull()).toPandas()
np.isnan(pdTest2['b'].astype(np.float64)) 
0    True
1    True
Name: b, dtype: bool
```

Comment: This definitely helps, but isn't strictly speaking an answer to my question of how to convert more consistently. It just avoids issues in this case. But perhaps there could still be other issues with this inconsistent conversion in other ways (that I can't think of right now).

Comment: I don't think you can - it's an expected behaviour because `numpy` will have `np.isnan` implemented on native types only, while `pyspark` has no concept of `NaN`, instead it translates Python `None` to JVM `null`. This means that otherwise you need check for `NaN`, catch exceptions and then check for `None`, since you're checking for two different types.

Comment: @Willem I've added little bit more flavour with an alternative solution with taking your second array as type `np.float64` to make `np.isnan` is working. Hope this helps and answers more clearly :)